# Loop the below way in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a column 'Distance' with value from 0 to n. I want to write a loop such that, if distance is above 0.5km it should say M1. When it is less than 0.5, it should be H1. When it crosses 0.5 again it should give **M2**.

My dataset: [image]

Expected output: [image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Why isn't it "normal loop"? what is "normal loop" anyway?

Comment: i mean to say, if it is just assigning **H** and **M**, i can do it. Sorry

Comment: Please try some code first.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't know what you mean. What have you tried so far? This is a simple loop with `if else`.

Comment: i tried this ```for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if (df.loc[i+1,'Distance_km'] <= 0.5):
        df.loc[i+1, "Status"]='H'```

Comment: but i want it to assing h1, h2 etc instead of H

Comment: I tried this but the problem here is, it changes for every condition. My requirement is: If is less than 0.5 continously, it should assign one value. Please check my required output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm to get you started. Improve it to suit your needs

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

m_count = 0
h_count = 0
current = "H"

status_halt = []

for idx in df.index:
    if df["Distance_km"][idx] < 0.5:
        if current == "M":
            h_count += 1
        status_halt.append(f"H{h_count}")
        current = "H"
    elif df["Distance_km"][idx] > 0.5:
        if current == "H":
            m_count += 1
        status_halt.append(f"M{m_count}")
        current = "M"

df["Status_halt"] = status_halt
```

Comment: Yup i can work around with this :) Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop on a DataFrame? It’s a bad `for` loop, at that.

Comment: What do you think is a better solution for this then?